# the element id is not being accepted a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to pass paramaters to a function i.e.

```
 animateDiv(div) {
  .....

}
```

this function works, but when i try to pass parameters to it like this, it deosnt work i.e.

```
$activeToggle.toggle("slow", function(){
            $(this).find(".anime_yellow").each(function (i,e){

            console.log(e.id); // this prints simple
            animateDiv(simple); // this works
            animateDiv(e.id);   //this deosnt work but it prints 'simple' 


         });
```

when i pass hardcore values into the function it works i.e. `animateDiv(simple)` , if i try to put a variable which holds the same thing, it deosnt work `animateDiv(e.id)`, thanks

the full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwhtv/22/

Comment: What is the difference between a string and a DOM Node? ;)

Comment: cause it just string(id), not element~

Comment: @user1042031 It's the span with id `simple`

Comment: @Andreas : Ohh Thanks ;) just noticed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `animateDiv` is assuming you'll pass in an object.  Note the following lines:

```
function animateDiv(div){
   var text = $('#' + div.id).text(); //div is assumed to be a div element
```

If you wanted to pass in an `id`, you'd have to change that to:

```
function animateDiv(divId){
   var text = $('#' + divId).text();
```

And of course update other references to `div.id` as well.

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwhtv/22/

Answer (score 1):

From your jsfiddle:

```
function animateDiv(div){

var text = $('#' + div.id).text();

var doAnimate = function() {
    $('span.' + div.id).each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
                .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );
        },that.index()*100);
    });
}
```

You're passing the ID, but in the function you expect the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$activeToggle.toggle("slow", function(){
      $(this).find(".anime_yellow").each(function (i,e){

            console.log(e.id); // this prints simple
            animateDiv(simple); // this works
            animateDiv(e.id);   //this deosnt work but it prints 'simple' 


         });
```

In function (i, e), e is  element.

```
<span id="simple" class="anime_yellow">
```

To get the id of , you need to use $(e).attr('id');

```
animateDiv($(e).attr('id'));
```

Currenty you passed the parameter as object. If you pass the id of an object(span), you need to change id of span as follows.

```
function animateDiv(div){
// var text = $('#' + div.id).text();
var text = $('#' + div).text();

var doAnimate = function() {
    //  $('span.' + div.id).each(function() {
     $('span.' + div).each(function() {

        var that = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.animate({ fontSize: "90px" }, 1500 )
                .animate({ fontSize: "50px" }, 1500 );
        },that.index()*100);
    });
}
```